# How can I secure my game from fraud and abuse?

Tags: android, security, firebase-security

I have a game uses Firestore, When the player complete the certain level the game will give him 50 points and will be save the data in Firestore.

Let's suppose someone did reverse engineering for my game and made change from 50 points to 1000 points in code and he rebuild the APK and play my game with the same Firestore database, Now when the player complete certain level the game will give him 1000 points and will be save the data in Firestore and that considered hacked data.

I don't care if someone did reverse engineering of my game and republish it as new game with his own Firestore, But I care about hackers who changed the data on my Firestore

How can I secure my game from fraud and abuse.

Comment: `How can I secure my game from fraud and abuse.` realistically, you cant. especially not with something like firebase. while firebase is amazing, you'd probably have more control over security and data you receive if you had your own backend which could then further process the information received, but even if you weren't using firebase, your question is too broad. only really valid option would be to require some sort of authentication before being able to write

Comment: Sensitive code should always be placed on server side, not on client side. If you still want to stick with Firebase only you should move the relevant code to server side called "Cloud Functions" https://cloud.google.com/functions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you hear about the [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check). It would restrict access to your Firebase serviced only from your App or Web Page.

You can link your App with App Check so Firebase would only work with your App. In that case even a 100% reverse engeenered game would not work at all.